# R, ggplot, Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10):x, y

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression

I apologize, as I know this question has been asked many times before, but it is my first time using R and although I've looked at the other questions, I'm still unsure of how to fix mine.
I'm attempting to create a logistic regression, but I keep getting the error that is "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10):x, y"

This is what I have done thus far:

```
> unemp<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
> attach(unemp)
> unemp
   Month..2008. OUR LT.Un NLT.Un
1           Jan 4.8     0      7
2           Feb 4.7     1      5
3           Mar 4.8     1      1
4           Apr 4.7     1     13
5           May 5.3     7      4
6           Jun 5.9     4     13
7           Jul 6.5     0     14
8           Aug 6.8     1     11
9          Sept 6.8     9     13
10          Oct 7.1     3     13

> LT<-cbind(LT.Un,NLT.Un)
> logrl<-glm(LT~OUR,family=binomial)
> summary(logrl)

Call:
glm(formula = LT ~ OUR, family = binomial)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.6886  -1.4094  -0.3574   0.7103   2.9993  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -1.59325    1.50879  -1.056    0.291
OUR          0.05707    0.24589   0.232    0.816

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 28.018  on 9  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 27.964  on 8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 51.157

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(unemp, aes(x=OUR, y=LT)) + 
     geom_point() + 
     stat_smooth(method="glm", method.args=list(family="binomial"), se=FALSE)

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10): x, y
```

Does anyone know what would be causing it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What tutorial are you using that recommends both `file.choose()` and `attach()`? Both are really bad habits to start off with.

Comment: I am using this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEllScuasns) for the beginning and until the summary(logrl); after that, to make the graph, I used this [link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Statistical_analysis/Logistic_regression/)

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a column called LT in the data frame unemp. (That will likely fix this immediate error, but many of the things you are doing here put youat much greater risk of encountering more errors downthe road, particularly as a beginner. Any site/tutorial that recommends attach() should simply be ignored)

Comment: The way it was explained in the tutorial (although I fear it to be dubious, at this point) was that `cbind()` could be used to bind that the "yes"s and "no"s needed for the logistic regression, in this case, yes being `LT.Un` and no being `NLT.Un`, to a heading, which I made LT. How should I change `aes(x=OUR, y=LT)` to reflect this? And I do apologize for the cardinal sin of `attach()`.

Comment: So, did this solve your problem?

Comment: You can't reconcile your use of `glm` and `ggplot`. `glm` does accept a response that is a matrix, but that format of data is basically nonsensical from `ggplot`'s perspective. You can map one column to `y` at a time in ggplot, and that's it. You can always plot the fitted values in their own layer taking them from the model object.

Comment: Yeah, what I ended up doing was just reformatting LT to have all zeros and ones instead of a summary of the data. Thank you, everyone, for all of your help!

Comment: If you have solved the problem, please answer your own question.